# Control of a stepper Motor direcction rotation using Limit switches to change the rotation when an interrupt is trigger by the limitSwitch Sensor

Tags: arduino-c++

I'm trying to control several stepper Motors, but for this example what I want to achieve is that when the limit Switch is triggered it will change the direction of the rotation of the motor, so for testing purposes I write a code that it's supposed to change the rotation of the motor when the Limit Switch associated to the stepper motor instance generates an interrupt. the idea is to create an instance of **LimitSwitch** class for each **StepperMotor** that will be associated to each motor instance by writing a "glue routines" that keep track of which instance of the class is triggering the interrupt.

I wrote the following code by it doesn't change the rotation of the motor, however the interruption, it's trigger and the corresponding function of the **StepperMotor. cpp** class gets called, the problem I think it's that the doesn´t hold the previous value direction Motion

```
enum Motion {CLOCKWISE, ANTICLOCKWISE};
```

and the typeOfControl:

```
enum TypeOfControl {WAVE_DRIVE, FULL_STEP, HALF_STEP};
```

to reverse the correct matrix, i tried to declare the variables that hold this values statics so the value  of the variables in the previous call gets carried through the next function call but it doesn't work either.

I hope there is enough explanation, here is the code if some more details are needed to let me know please, thanks for the help and sorry if the code it's not the best.

**StepMotor.ino**

```
#include "StepperMotor.h"
#include "ControlMotorParameters.h"
#include "Delay.h"
#include "LimitSwitch.h"
#include "HC_SR04.h"
#include "Joystick.h"
#include "EncoderSensor.h"


//define the pin_out where the constroler of the the stepper motor is connected to the uC ARDUINO MEGA
// #define IN1_PIN_M1 22
// #define IN2_PIN_M1 24
// #define IN3_PIN_M1 26
// #define IN4_PIN_M1 28

// #define IN1_PIN_M2 31
// #define IN2_PIN_M2 33
// #define IN3_PIN_M2 35
// #define IN4_PIN_M2 37

// #define IN1_PIN_M3 30
// #define IN2_PIN_M3 32
// #define IN3_PIN_M3 34
// #define IN4_PIN_M3 36
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

#define IN1_PIN_M2 12
#define IN2_PIN_M2 11
#define IN3_PIN_M2 10
#define IN4_PIN_M2 9

//LimitSwitch pin interrupt 
#define LIMIT_SWITCH1_PIN 2

//HC_SR04 pins connections
#define ECHO_PIN 3
#define TRIGGER_PIN 4

//Joystick pin
#define X_AXIS_PIN A0
#define Y_AXIS_PIN A1 

// //Encoder interrupt Pin
// #define ENCODER_OUTPUT_PIN 3

Delay mDelay(5000);

//byte controlerPinsM1[] = {IN1_PIN_M1, IN2_PIN_M1, IN3_PIN_M1, IN4_PIN_M1};
byte controlerPinsM2[] = {IN1_PIN_M2, IN2_PIN_M2, IN3_PIN_M2, IN4_PIN_M2};
//byte controlerPinsM3[] = {IN1_PIN_M3, IN2_PIN_M3, IN3_PIN_M3, IN4_PIN_M3};

//instances of the LimitSwitches 
LimitSwitch* LimitSwitch::numInstancesOfswitches[6] = {NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL};

HC_SR04* HC_SR04::HC_SR04_instances[1] = {NULL};
HC_SR04 distanceSensor(ECHO_PIN, TRIGGER_PIN);

//joystick
Joystick joystick(X_AXIS_PIN, Y_AXIS_PIN);

static Motion CurrentDir = ANTICLOCKWISE;

//StepperMotor stepperM1(controlerPinsM1);              // Stepper Object M1
StepperMotor stepperM2(controlerPinsM2, joystick);
//StepperMotor stepperM3(controlerPinsM3);


LimitSwitch limitSwitch1(stepperM2,LIMIT_SWITCH1_PIN);

//Encoder Sensor
// Encoder* Encoder::instances[1] = {NULL};
// Encoder encoderSensor(ENCODER_OUTPUT_PIN);

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  delay(100);

  distanceSensor.init();

  joystick.init();

  mDelay.init();

  stepperM2.init();
  stepperM2.setTypeOfControl(WAVE_DRIVE);
  stepperM2.setRotationDirection(CLOCKWISE);
  
 
  limitSwitch1.init();

  //encoderSensor.init();
}

void loop() {
  stepperM2.rotate();  
}
```

**StepperMotor.h**

```
#ifndef STEPPER_MOTOR_H
#define STEPPER_MOTOR_H

#include "wiring_private.h"
#include <stdint.h>
#include "Arduino.h"
#include "ControlMotorParameters.h"
#include "UtilityClass.h"
#include "Delay.h"
#include "Joystick.h"


//Joystick pin
#define X_AXIS_PIN A0
#define Y_AXIS_PIN A1 

class StepperMotor{
  private:
    
    // pionut where the Controler Pins of each Motor  are connected to the uC
    byte* ptrToPinOutControler;
    int sizePinControllerArray;
    
    //delay to adjust the speed of the motor
    Joystick joystick;
    Delay delayBetweenSteps;
    
    
    TypeOfControl control;
    Motion previousDirection;  
    bool changeRotationDir;  


    // Control sequence of the Matrix that energized the inductors of the stator in function the the system Control selected for the Motor
    byte waveDriveMatrix    [4][4] = {{1,0,0,0},{0,1,0,0},{0,0,1,0},{0,0,0,1}};
    byte fullStepMatrix     [4][4] = {{1,1,0,0},{0,1,1,0},{0,0,1,1},{1,0,0,1}};
    byte halfSteppingMatrix [8][4] = {{1,0,0,0},{1,1,0,0},{0,1,0,0},{0,1,1,0},{0,0,1,0},{0,0,1,1},{0,0,0,1},{1,0,0,1}};
    byte** controlMotorMatrix;      //dynamic array created to control the motor

    // this vars store the numbers of rows and columns depending of the type of Control Matrix
    int rows    ;
    int columns ;
    
    bool stopMotor;
  
    typedef void (StepperMotor::*fptrRotate)();               //fptr that will execute the sequence of the motor Controler Matrix 
    fptrRotate rotatefptr;

    //this Template Function return the number of rows and columns of the Control matrix to drive the inductors in the stator of the Motor 
    template <class T, unsigned N, unsigned N1>
      int getLength(T (&)[N][N1],int position){
        return (position == 0) ? N:N1;
    }

    void rotateFullStep();                                    // rotate the Motor using a fullStep System Control   
    void rotateWaveDrive();                                   // rotate the Motor using a rotateWaveDrive System Control
    void rotateHalfStepping();                                // rotate the Motor using a rotateHafStepping System Control 
 
  public:
    
    //Constructor
    StepperMotor(byte* ptrToPinOutControler, Joystick joystick);    // Constructor of the Stepper Object passing the pin array where the controler it's connected

    //Function prototypes
    void init();                                              // Configure the pinout of the uC where the Controler it's connected to
    void rotate();                                            // Rotate the motor in the direction pass in as a parameter
    void start();
    void stop();
    void setRotationDirection(Motion direction);
    void setTypeOfControl(TypeOfControl newTypeOfControl);    // function to change the type of control of the motor
    TypeOfControl getTypeOfControl();
    Motion getPreviousDir();
    void ChangeRotationDir();
};

#endif
```

**StepperMotor.cpp**

```
#include "Print.h"
#include "Arduino.h"
#include "HardwareSerial.h"
#include "StepperMotor.h"
#include <math.h>


StepperMotor::StepperMotor(byte* ptrToPinOutControler, Joystick joystick): ptrToPinOutControler(ptrToPinOutControler), joystick(joystick){
  this->delayBetweenSteps = Delay(joystick.getSpeedForTheMotor()/4096);
};

void StepperMotor::init(){
  previousDirection = CLOCKWISE;  
  control = HALF_STEP;
  sizePinControllerArray = 0 ;
  stopMotor = false;

  joystick.init();
  delayBetweenSteps.init();

  
  int i = 0;
  //Configure the pins of the uC as an OUTPUT to send the signal  
  while (*(ptrToPinOutControler+i)) {
    pinMode(*ptrToPinOutControler, OUTPUT);
    digitalWrite(*ptrToPinOutControler, LOW);
    i++;
    sizePinControllerArray++;
  }
}

void StepperMotor::setTypeOfControl(TypeOfControl newTypeOfControl){  
  control = newTypeOfControl;
  //set the control fprt for the motor in function of the selected Type of Control
  switch (control) {
    case FULL_STEP:{
      rotatefptr = &StepperMotor::rotateFullStep; 
      break;
    }
    case HALF_STEP:{
      rotatefptr = &StepperMotor::rotateHalfStepping;
      break;
    }
    case WAVE_DRIVE:{
      rotatefptr = &StepperMotor::rotateWaveDrive;
      break;
    }
  }
}

TypeOfControl StepperMotor::getTypeOfControl(){
  return control;
}

Motion StepperMotor::getPreviousDir(){
  return previousDirection;
}

void StepperMotor::rotateWaveDrive(){
  rows    = getLength(waveDriveMatrix,0);
  columns = getLength(waveDriveMatrix, 1);

  for (int i = 0; i<rows;) {
    for (int j = 0 ; j<columns  ; j++) {
      digitalWrite(*(ptrToPinOutControler + j), waveDriveMatrix[i][j]);
    }
    if(delayBetweenSteps.isDelayTimeElapsed()) i++;
  }
}

void StepperMotor::rotateFullStep(){
  rows    = getLength(fullStepMatrix,0) ;
  columns = getLength(fullStepMatrix, 1);

  for (int i = 0; i<rows;) {
    for (int j = 0 ; j<columns  ; j++) {
      digitalWrite(*(ptrToPinOutControler + j), fullStepMatrix[i][j]);
    }
    if(delayBetweenSteps.isDelayTimeElapsed()) i++;
  }
  
}

void StepperMotor::rotateHalfStepping(){
  rows    = getLength(halfSteppingMatrix,0);
  columns = getLength(halfSteppingMatrix, 1);

  for (int i = 0; i<rows;) {
    for (int j = 0 ; j<columns  ; j++) {
      digitalWrite(*(ptrToPinOutControler + j), halfSteppingMatrix[i][j]);
    }
    if(delayBetweenSteps.isDelayTimeElapsed()) i++;
  }
}


void StepperMotor::setRotationDirection(Motion direction){
  (direction == CLOCKWISE) ? Serial.println("dir = CLOCKWISE"):Serial.println("dir = ANTCLOCKWISE");
  (previousDirection == CLOCKWISE) ? Serial.println("previouseDir = CLOCKWISE"): Serial.println("previouseDir = ANTICLOCKWISE");  

  if(direction != previousDirection) {
    switch (control) {
      case FULL_STEP:{
        Serial.println("reverse FULL_STEP Matrix");
        UtilityClass::reverseMatrix(fullStepMatrix, getLength(fullStepMatrix,0), getLength(fullStepMatrix,1));
        break;
      }
      case HALF_STEP:{
        Serial.println("reverse HALF_STEP Matrix");
         UtilityClass::reverseMatrix(halfSteppingMatrix, getLength(halfSteppingMatrix,0), getLength(halfSteppingMatrix,1));
        break;
      }
      case WAVE_DRIVE:{
        Serial.println("reverse WAVE_DRIVE Matrix");
        UtilityClass::reverseMatrix(waveDriveMatrix, getLength(waveDriveMatrix,0), getLength(waveDriveMatrix,1));
        break;
      }
    }
    previousDirection = direction;
  }   
}

void StepperMotor::start(){
  stopMotor = false;
}

void StepperMotor::stop(){
  stopMotor = (stopMotor == false) ? true:false;
}

void StepperMotor::ChangeRotationDir(){
  Serial.println(changeRotationDir);
  changeRotationDir = true;
   Serial.println(changeRotationDir);
  if (changeRotationDir) {
    if ( previousDirection == CLOCKWISE) {
      setRotationDirection(ANTICLOCKWISE);
    }else{
      setRotationDirection(CLOCKWISE);
    }
  }
  changeRotationDir = false;
   Serial.println(changeRotationDir);
}

void StepperMotor::rotate(){
  
  delayBetweenSteps.updateDelayTime((control == HALF_STEP) ?          // This delay will set the speed of the motor: min.(seg/rpm) -> max.(seg/rpm)
    joystick.getSpeedForTheMotor() / 4.096 :                          // for the HALF_STEP control the min. delay can be 1ms due to the matrix is double size compare to the other type of Control          
    round(joystick.getSpeedForTheMotor() / 4.096)                     // roundUp the speed value (min. delay between steps is 2ms)     
  ); 

  if(!stopMotor)(this->*rotatefptr)();                               // To call a member functions through a pointer -> this will call the appropiate control function for the motor   
}
```

**UtilityCLass.h**

```
#ifndef UTILITY_CLASS_H
#define UTILITY_CLASS_H

#include "ControlMotorParameters.h"
#include "StepperMotor.h"

#include "Arduino.h"

class UtilityClass{
  private:
    static void swap(byte* a , byte* b );                  // Utility function used to swap two elements in the Matrix
    
  public:
    //Function Prototypes
    static void reverseMatrix(byte arr[][4],int rows,int columns);       // Function in charge of reverse the 2D matrix for controling the inductors of the motor to charge the rotation direction
    static void printArray(byte arr[][4], int row, int column);          // Print the values of the array

    template <typename T> 
    T **AllocateDynamicArray( int nRows, int nCols){
      T **dynamicArray;
      dynamicArray = new T*[nRows];
      for( int i = 0 ; i < nRows ; i++ ){
        dynamicArray[i] = new T [nCols];
      }  
      return dynamicArray;
    }

    template <typename T>
    void FreeDynamicArray(T** dArray){
      delete [] *dArray;
      delete [] dArray;
    }
};

#endif
```

**UtilityCLass.cpp**

```
#include "Arduino.h"
#include "HardwareSerial.h"
#include "UtilityClass.h"

void UtilityClass::swap(byte* a , byte* b){
  byte temp = *a;
  *a = *b;
  *b = temp;
}

void UtilityClass::reverseMatrix(byte arr[][4],int rows, int columns){
  Serial.print("Original Array -> ");
  printArray(arr, rows, columns);

  //we will used a nested loop to traverse each row and columns of the matrix
  for (int i = 0; i<rows; i++) {
    // we need to define the starting and ending point of the iteration throug the MAtrix array
    int startIndex = 0;            
    int endIndex = columns-1;

    //we will swap the first element of the array with the last one and so on until we get to the the middle {1,0,0,0} -> {0,0,0,1}
    while (startIndex < endIndex) {
      //swap element
      swap(&arr[i][startIndex], &arr[i][endIndex]);

      //move the indexed towards the middle
      startIndex++;
      endIndex--;
    }
  }
  
  Serial.print("reversed Array -> ");
  printArray(arr, rows, columns);
  Serial.println();
}

void UtilityClass::printArray(byte (*arr)[4],int row, int column){  
  for (int i = 0; i<row; i++) {
    if(i==0) Serial.print("{");
    for (int j=0; j<column; j++) {
      if(j==0)Serial.print("{");
      Serial.print(arr[i][j]);
      (j>=0 && j<column-1) ? Serial.print(","):Serial.print("");
    }
    Serial.print("},");
  }
  Serial.println("}");
}
```

**LimitSwitch.h**

```
#ifndef LIMIT_SWITCH_H
#define LIMIT_SWITCH_H

#include <Arduino.h>
#include "StepperMotor.h"
#include "ControlMotorParameters.h"       

// num of instances of limitSwitches capable of trigger the ISR
#define NUM_OF_SWITCHES 6   
#define DEBOUNCE_DELAY_TIME 50    //ms 

class LimitSwitch{
  private:
    static LimitSwitch* numInstancesOfswitches[NUM_OF_SWITCHES];    /** To keep track of which intances of the Object triggers the ISR.
     Here we store the instance of the LimitSwitch class created in tne main which will be associated to a motor */
    
    StepperMotor motor;

    byte interruptPin;

    //for debouncing
    unsigned long previousTime = millis();
    byte buttonState = HIGH;
    byte previousButtonState = HIGH;
    

    bool debounceLimitSwitch();               // To avoid reading 
    static void reverseRotationISR();         // definition of the "glue ruotine" that will check which limitSwitch instance triggered the ISR 

  public:

    //Constructor
    LimitSwitch(StepperMotor motor, byte interruptPin);
    
    //function prototypes
    void init();
    void changeDir();
};

#endif
```

**LimitSwitch.cpp**

```
#include "HardwareSerial.h"
#include "Arduino.h"
#include "LimitSwitch.h"

LimitSwitch::LimitSwitch(StepperMotor motor, byte interruptPin):motor(motor), interruptPin(interruptPin){}

//ISR's
void LimitSwitch::reverseRotationISR(){
  for(int i = 0 ; i < NUM_OF_SWITCHES; i++){
    if(LimitSwitch::numInstancesOfswitches[i] != NULL) LimitSwitch::numInstancesOfswitches[i]->changeDir();
  }
}

void LimitSwitch::init(){
  pinMode(interruptPin, INPUT_PULLUP);

  attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(interruptPin), reverseRotationISR, FALLING);
  numInstancesOfswitches[0] = this;
}

bool LimitSwitch::debounceLimitSwitch(){
  unsigned long timeNow = millis();                                                               // get the current time 
  buttonState = digitalRead(interruptPin);                                                        // read the current state of the pin that caused the interrupt
  if ((buttonState != previousButtonState) && (timeNow - previousTime > DEBOUNCE_DELAY_TIME)) {
    previousTime = timeNow;
    previousButtonState = buttonState;
    return true;
  }else {
    return false;
  }
}

void LimitSwitch::changeDir(){
  if (debounceLimitSwitch()) {
    motor.ChangeRotationDir(); 
  }  
}
```

Control of the directional rotation of a Stepper Motor using external interrupt from another class

Answer (score 0):

Just for if someone encounters a similar problem, i fix the issue that i was having by declare the Control variables of the stepper motor as **inline static** so when the interrupt is trigger from an external class the inline keyword what does (or at least that it's what I understand from reading some documentation that allows you to initialize the value of static variables directly in the class a that will hold the value, in this case the array from one call to another of the interrupt and If this is defined more than one time, the compiler merges them all into a single object in final program.)

I may be wrong, but now the code is working fine. this it`s what i change form
**StepperMotor.h**

```
inline static TypeOfControl control = HALF_STEP ;                                                           
inline static  Motion previousDirection = CLOCKWISE;  
bool changeRotationDir;  

inline static byte waveDriveMatrix    [4][4] = {{1,0,0,0},{0,1,0,0},{0,0,1,0},{0,0,0,1}};
inline static byte fullStepMatrix     [4][4] = {{1,1,0,0},{0,1,1,0},{0,0,1,1},{1,0,0,1}};
inline static byte halfSteppingMatrix [8][4] = {{1,0,0,0},{1,1,0,0},{0,1,0,0},{0,1,1,0},{0,0,1,0},{0,0,1,1},{0,0,0,1},{1,0,0,1}};
inline static byte** controlMotorMatrix;
```